# Strange issue with ping

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hamachi

I have created a Minecraft server with two more friends, the problem is that my Friend1 has like 200 ping and the Friend2 has a normal ping, but when my Friend1 connects to Friend2's server Friend1 and me have normal ping. I have made a ping to Friend1's IP and it comes out with a normal ping, but when Friend1 does a ping to me it has ~140 ping.

Answer (score 1):

Friend1 seems to have increased ping communicating with your specific location.

Ping is hard to diagnose without more detail, but it sounds to me like he is farther away from you than Friend2.

When Friend2 hosts, he is likely more centralized to both You and Friend1.

It's possible that network hardware on either side may be playing a role in this, but more likely, it's simply due to location.